# Possible to use newline inside roxygen2 code block?

Tags: r, documentation, r-package

I'm wondering if it's possible to insert newlines inside code blocks in roxygen2 when documenting a function?

If I have something inside `\code{}`, roxygen2 collapses all newlines into single spaces by default.  I tried inserting `\cr` inside to enforce a line break, and I get the desired behaviour, but then I get a WARNING when I "R CMD CHECK".  Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
#' \code{
#'   multiple
#'   lines
#' }
```

Comment: Note that this is not really a roxygen issue but rather a general R documentation issue, see [the manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Marking-text).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `\preformatted` instead of `\code`. `\code` is for inline code (works like ``` `` ``` on SO) and `\preformatted` is for verbatim blocks (like indentation on SO).

```
#' \preformatted{
#'   multiple
#'   lines
#' }
```

Note that the initial line break, just after `{`, will also be part of the code block, so you might want to consider removing it.